# mapMappableContainerException on adding Spring Aspect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, spring-aop

i want to add a Aspect on the set method of pass.

```
public Response responseMsg(@QueryParam("name") String name,
        @DefaultValue("Nothing to say") @QueryParam("email") String email,
        @QueryParam("date") String date, @QueryParam("pass") String pass) {

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    UserDetails user = (UserDetails) context.getBean("user");

    user.setEmailID(email);
    if (name.length() != 0)
        user.setName(name);
    user.setDate(date);
    user.setPass(pass);
    session.save(user);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return Response.status(200).entity("success").build();

}
```

i added one class

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass {

    @Before("execution(public void setPass(..))")
    public void LoggingAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Logging advice run");
    }    
}
```

if i remove

```
@Before("execution(public void setPass(..))")
```

everything runs fine

however with current code facing the exception below

but before that i can see the logging print.

Logging advice run

```
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$738ee61b
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    at com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST.responseMsg(HelloWorldREST.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 21, 2015 11:19:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-helloworld-serlvet] in context with path [/JAXRS-HelloWorld] threw exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$738ee61b
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1192)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1403)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:757)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:749)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745)
    at com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST.responseMsg(HelloWorldREST.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Debug :

user object without Aspect
[image]

user object with Aspect
[image]

UserDetails.java

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNameAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

@Entity
public class UserDetails implements ApplicationContextAware,BeanNameAware,InitializingBean,DisposableBean{

    /*Address officeAddress;

    public Address getOfficeAddress() {
        return officeAddress;
    }

    public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
        this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
    }

    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }

    public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }

    Address homeAddress;*/

    @Column
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column
    String password;

    public String getPass() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPass(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column
    String adminName;

    public String getAdminName() {
        return adminName;
    }

    public void setAdminName(String adminName) {
        this.adminName = adminName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmailID() {
        return EmailID;
    }

    public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
        EmailID = emailID;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Column
    @Id
    String EmailID;

    @Column
    String date;

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        System.out.println(beanName);

    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
            throws BeansException {
        System.out.println(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("initialising bean called from after properties set");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("disposable bean distroy method");

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void myDestroy(){
        System.out.println("Pre Destroy method from annotation");       
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void afterConstruct(){
        System.out.println("called after construction from annotation");
    }

}
```

Comment: ..your pointcut looks strange (I've never seen a `void`in there), but more concrete: **have you** configured `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature=true` in your web.xml?

Comment: @xerx593 "your pointcut looks strange (I've never seen a voidin there)" .... checked one tutorial so there is no issue with it. However, i didnt add this `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature=true`.could you please give me the reason to add this code. i debug somewhat and find that when 'session.save(user)' executes ...... it give the error.

Comment: I think you can forget about POJOMappingFeature(?!...it is relevant for mapping object<->json). The error message, you have, is straightforward: "**Uknown(hibernate) entity: com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.UserDetails...**", and you obviously try to save that to database...can you show us the hibernate config/annotations for UserDetails?

Comment: @xerx593 Added the images how user object change with aspect and without aspect along with UserDetails.java

Comment: humm, this is a tough one! (thx for the updates!) Please try changing: `session.save(user);`to `session.save(UserDetails.class.getName(), user);` ..according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236870/592355)

Comment: @xerx593 not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75963/discussion-between-xerx593-and-sparsh-khandelwal).